# With out static keywork in main method getting the exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I am unable to find the proper reason for this.

```
 public class MainTest {    
    static public  void main(String[] args) {

            System.out.println("HAI");
    }
  }
```

When I run this code  output is:HAI

```
static class MainTest { 
        static void main(String[] args) {

                System.out.println("HAI");
        }
      }
```

This code compiles fine.But when I run I am getting Exception `Main method not public`

```
public class MainTest { 
        public  void main(String[] args) {

                System.out.println("HAI");
        }
      }
```

This code compiles fine.But when I run I am getting Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

Can some one explain reasons for this behavior .

If I did not specify static why it is not taking as instance method. 
When I do not used outside of the class why I need to make the main method as public?
If because of static main method is calling can I place main method logic in any static method with out using main method?

Comment: Because the main method is the entry point. Is as to be public so that it can be called from anywhere (without public, it can only be called from within the package). It has to be static so it an be called without having to instantiate the class. That is just how Java was designed.

Comment: @Supericy But here i am not accessing outside the package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword `public` indicates that any class outside the class that contains the method may call this method.  This is the case with main, where some obscure object of the JVM needs to call the main method in this class.

The keyword `static` indicates that the method does not require any specific properties of the class it is in.  Since every java program starts with no objects created aside from those inherent in the JVM, it was decided by the Java developers to make main static.

In short, there should never be a case where main needs to be an instance method of a class, as that class would have to be created first, and there is no way to tell that to the JVM prior to actually calling the main function.

Comment: Then why i use main method.Can i use any  static method

Comment: The JVM simply expects that the entry point for any application will be called main.  (This is to help keep developers from shooting themselves in the foot.)

Comment: What will happen if i put the main method code into a static method

Comment: You would need to have main call that secondary static method if you wanted that code to be executed.

Comment: ok i understand about this.but why public ? i am not accessing this main in any where

Answer (score 1):

public static void main(String args[])

You should always include the 3 keywords: public, static, and void

Comment: Why ?i need the reasons and explanation

Comment: I think the explanation here will suffice: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/main-public-static-java-void-method-why.html

Answer (score 1):

If a method does not have any specifier (as in your second example), then it is only accessible by other java files in the same package (same folder). This causes problems when the JVM tries to run your code, since it's not part of that package.

To understand your third point, you have to understand how instance methods work. They can only be called on an *instance* -- so the JVM would have to instantiate your class using a constructor before calling `main`. The designers of Java decided it would be simpler to require that `main` be static, so it causes an error if it's not static.

Comment: from where jvm will run my code.I am not calling main method any where

Comment: Then why i use main method.Can i use any  static method